# Nesting storing and sorting in struct in angular

Tags: angularjs, struct

Ok, so I have a JSON file with lots of information that can be sorted many ways.  The actual JSON is too large, but for a relevant example:

```
$myData = 
{
  "id":1,
  "author_id":[17],
  "date":"10/1/1996",
  "title":"Article1"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "author_id":[16,17],
  "date":"9/1/1996",
  "title":"Article2"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "author_id":[16],
  "date":"6/1/1996",
  "title":"Article3"
};
```

I want to be able to sort this into a struct with the basic structure like:

```
$myDataByAuthor = 
{"17" = 
    {
    "id":1,
    "date":"10/1/1996",
    "title":"Article1"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "date":"9/1/1996",
    "title":"Article2"
    }
},
{"16" = 
    {
    "id":3,
    "date":"6/1/1996",
    "title":"Article3"
    };
    {
    "id":2,
    "date":"9/1/1996",
    "title":"Article2"
    }
};
```

I know the syntax there is bad, but I'm not really sure how to lay this out which is why I'm asking.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to turn around and, using ng-repeat in my code be able to output something to effect of:

```
Author with id 16
    6/1/1996 - Article3
    9/1/1996 - Article2

Author with id 17
    9/1/1996 - Article2
   10/1/1996 - Article1
```

I'm just not seeing how to get this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly restructure it that way, and here is a fiddle and code of the function that would restructure it that way for you.

```
var table = {}

myData.forEach(function(element){
    element.author_id.forEach(function(id){
        table[id] = table[id] || []
        table[id].push(element)
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q40yhhko/

Comment: When I do this then attempt to dump the struct like so: `{{articlesByAuthor}}` (I called it that instead of table) I get an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data is:

```
$myData = [{ "id":1, "author_id":[17], "date":"10/1/1996", "title":"Article1"},
           {"id":2, "author_id":[16,17], "date":"9/1/1996", "title":"Article2"},
           {"id":3, "author_id":[16], "date":"6/1/1996", "title":"Article3" }];
```

To form the required JSON use below code

```
$scope.requiredJSON = {};  //FORMATED JSON DATA
angular.foreach($myData, function(value, index){
     angular.foreach(value.author_id, function(innerVal, innerIndex){
         $scope.requiredJSON[innerVal] = $scope.requiredJSON[innerVal] || [];
         $scope.requiredJSON[innerVal].push({id: value.id, date: value.date, title: value.title});
     })
});
```

Following is the output:

```
{17: [{"id":1, "date":"10/1/1996", "title":"Article1" },
                {"id":2, "date":"9/1/1996", "title":"Article2" }], 
           16: [{"id":2, "date":"9/1/1996", "title":"Article2" }]};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AmitParrikar/uzv2p72b/2/

Comment: When I do this then attempt to dump the struct like so: `{{articlesByAuthor}}` (I called it that instead of requiredJSON) I get an empty array.